# Role based authorization in asp.net web api using ad access token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, role-base-authorization

I need to implement role based authorization for asp .net  web api
from native client application the access token will be sent in the header ,
so when i give [Authorize] attribute to my web api it is working fine,but when i give [Authorize(Role="Admin")] it is giving unauthorized error,
then whenever check for role in the claims it is always null.

My startup.cs is

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],               
            });

        }
```

and i have applied authorize attribute for a method

```
   [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<UserDetails> TestAuthorization()
        {
                    string upn = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            var role = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role);
           return null;
        }
```

here the role value is always null

Please help me on this